# Costum ReST post route function view not found cakephp 3

Tags: php, rest, cakephp

i try to build a custom POST route for ReST API in cakephp 3, but when i want to connect to the url i got  result:

> The view for CalculatedpricesController::getCosts() was not found.

My url to connect to ReST like this :

```
http://localhost/test/api/calculatedprices/getCosts
```

here's the route code:

```
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    Router::prefix('api', function ($routes) {
      $routes->extensions(['json', 'xml']);
      $routes->resources('Calculatedprices', [
         'map' => [
             'getCosts' => [
                 'action' => 'getCosts',
                 'method' => 'POST'
             ]
         ]
      ]);
    });
 $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

here's the controller code:

```
namespace App\Controller\Api;

use App\Controller\Api\AppController;

/**
 * Calculatedprices Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\CalculatedpricesTable $Calculatedprices
 */
class CalculatedpricesController extends AppController
{
    public function getCosts(){
      $originIdCity = $this->request->query('originCity');
      $originIdSub = $this->request->query('originSub');
      $courierId = $this->request->query('courierId');
      $serviceId = $this->request->query('serviceId');

      $conditions = array('origin_city_id' => $originIdCity,
                      'courier_id' => $courierId,
                      'service_id' => $serviceId
                     );

     if($originIdSub == ''){
       $condition = 'origin_subdistrict_id IS NULL';
       array_push($conditions,$condition);
     } else{
       $conditions['origin_subdistrict_id'] = $originIdSub;
     }

     $calculatedprices = $this->Calculatedprices->find('all', array(
           'conditions' => $conditions
          ));

     $this->set([
        'calculatedprices' => $calculatedprices,
        '_serialize' => ['calculatedprices']
     ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: you may use json extentaion like http://localhost/test/api/calculatedprices/getCosts.json

Comment: @tarikul05 thanks its working